# excel return Row for duplicate values found for expanding table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have large database with multiple tables rows & columns, nothing can be sorted.

I need to calculate the difference between the current row & a previous row that contains a given value in an expanding table. And possibly need to take into account multiple columns.

ie pseudo code;

=ROW()-if(any of all previous rows contain given value then return row of the most recent/last that contains this value)

Values can be duplicated & rows can be blank ("").
I can't use simple lookup, I've tried using index & match but can't seem to get it working so open to suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your post with some sample data and expected output result?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so managed to finally figure this out;

```
=IF($GI$8=AY13,ROW()-ROW($GI$9)-MATCH($AY$8+1,$AY$9:AY12,1)+1,"")
```

This forces match to return the last item as there's no proper match.

I was trying to make a 'perfect' match, which is why I wasn't getting the results I wanted.